# Calculate $\int_0^{\pi} \frac{ \cos ( kx ) }{ 1 - 2 \tau \cos (x ) } dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

I need to calculate the following integral:
$$\int_0^{\pi} \frac{ \cos ( kx ) }{ 1 - 2 \tau \cos (x ) } dx$$
for $k \geq 0$ and $| \tau | < \frac{1}{2}$. For $k=0$, I use the reparameterization $t = \tan (x /2)$, but I have no idea how to do it for $k \geq 1$.

Thanks!

Comment: Since $\cos(kx)$ can always be expressed as a polynomial in $\cos x$ and $\sin x,$ this is always possible to do in theory by the Weierstrass substitution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If contour integration is acceptable, let $\alpha=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4\tau^2}}{2\tau}$ and $1/\alpha=\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4\tau^2}}{2\tau}$.
$$\newcommand{\Res}{\operatorname*{Res}}
\begin{align}
\int_0^\pi\frac{\cos(kx)}{1-2\tau\cos(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\frac12\int_{-\pi}^\pi\frac{\cos(kx)+i\sin(kx)}{1-2\tau\cos(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag1\\
&=\frac12\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{z^k}{1-\tau z-\tau z^{-1}}\,\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{iz}\tag2\\
&=\frac1{2i}\oint\frac{z^k}{z-\tau z^2-\tau}\,\mathrm{d}z\tag3\\
&=\frac i{2\tau}\oint\frac{z^k}{(z-\alpha)(z-1/\alpha)}\,\mathrm{d}z\tag4\\
&=\frac1{2i\sqrt{1-4\tau^2}}\oint\left(\frac{z^k}{z-\alpha}-\frac{z^k}{z-1/\alpha}\right)\mathrm{d}z\tag5\\
&=\frac{\pi\alpha^k}{\sqrt{1-4\tau^2}}\tag6
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: since cosine is even, we can double the domain and divide by $2$
$\phantom{(1)\text{:}}$ since sine is odd, adding it to the integral has no effect
$(2)$: write trig functions as functions of $z$ on the unit circle ($z=e^{ix})$
$(3)$: simplify
$(4)$: factor the denominator
$(5)$: partial fractions
$(6)$: $1/\alpha$ is outside the unit circle and $\Res\limits_{z=\alpha}\left(\frac{z^k}{z-\alpha}\right)=\alpha^k$

Comment: This approach looks really elegant. I was able to follow steps 1--4 and 6, but unfortunately I got stuck at step 5. I know I have to apply the residue theorem and was able to calculate the first two residues as the $a_0$ coefficient in the Laurent series of $z^k$ and $z^{-k}$, respectively, in $z = \alpha$. However, I don't understand how to obtain the two residues in $z=0$.

Comment: @Marie: There are two singularities inside the unit circle: $z=\alpha$ and $z=0$. We compute the residues at each of these singularities, sum them, and multiply by $2\pi i$. Note that $\frac1{z-\alpha}=-\frac1\alpha\frac1{1-z/\alpha}$; this makes it easy to compute the series for $\frac1{z-\alpha}=-\frac1\alpha\left(1+\frac z\alpha+\frac{z^2}{\alpha^2}+\frac{z^3}{\alpha^3}+\dots\right)$.

Comment: Shouldn't we know the radius of circle to compute residue? (To decide whichever is inside the circle)

Comment: Our contour is the unit circle. That allows us to compute $\cos(kx)=\frac{z^k+z^{-k}}2$

Comment: I have simplified the computation by replacing $\cos(kx)$ by $\cos(kx)+i\sin(kx)$.

Answer (score 4):

Using the fact that for all $r\in (-1,1)$ and all real $x$,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty r^{|n|}e^{inx} =\frac{1-r^2}{1+r^2 - 2r\cos x}
\end{align*} (for background, this is the series representation of the [Poisson kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel)) we get
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{\pi} \frac{\cos(kx)}{1+r^2 -2r\cos x} dx =& \frac 1 2 \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{e^{ikx}}{1+r^2 -2r\cos x} dx\\
=&\frac 1{2}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \left(\frac 1 {1-r^2}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty r^{|n|}e^{inx}\right)e^{ikx} dx\\
=&\frac 1{2(1-r^2)}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty r^{|n|}\underbrace{\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{i(n+k)x} dx}_{=0 \ \text{ if }\ n+k\ne 0}\\
=&\frac { \pi r^k}{1-r^2}.
\end{align*} Now solving for $$\frac r{1+r^2} = \tau \ \ \Longrightarrow \ \ r=\frac {1-\sqrt{1-4\tau^2}}{2\tau} \in (-1,1)
$$ we finally get
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{\pi} \frac{\cos(kx)}{1 -2\tau\cos x} dx = &\frac{\pi r^k(1+r^2)}{1-r^2} =\frac{\pi}{ \sqrt{1-4\tau^2}}\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4\tau^2}}{2\tau}\right)^{k}.
\end{align*}

Comment: (+1) Nice approach.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thank you sir :)

Comment: (+1) Note that $\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4\tau^2}}{4\tau^2+\sqrt{1-4\tau^2}-1}=\frac1{\sqrt{1-4\tau^2}}$ might simplify the final answer.

Comment: @robjohn Oops, thank you for pointing out what I missed! :)

Comment: What is this symbol $\tau$ ?

Comment: I mean what does this represent

Comment: @Harshit Gupta It is a parameter of the integral $I(k,\tau)$ in question, which should be taken as constant when calculating the integral.

Comment: Exactly. I edited the question to make this point clearer.

Answer (score 3):

If $k\in\mathbb{N}$, the exercise immediately boils down to the determination of the coefficient of $\cos(kx)$ in the Fourier cosine series of 
$$(\text{assuming }|\tau|<\tfrac{1}{2})\qquad \frac{1}{1-2\tau\cos(x)}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\tau^n\left(e^{ix}+e^{-ix}\right)^n=\sum_{n\geq 0}\tau^n\sum_{m=0}^{n}\binom{n}{m}e^{(2m-n)ix} $$
which, by applying $\text{Re}$ to both sides, equals
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\tau^n \sum_{m=0}^{n}\binom{n}{m}\cos\left((2m-n)x\right). $$
Therefore the coefficient of $\cos(kx)$ is the sum of $\tau^n\binom{n}{m}$ where $2m-n=\pm k$ and $m\leq n$, and 
$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\cos(kx)}{1-2\tau\cos(x)}\,dx = \frac{\pi}{2}\cdot\left[\sum_{\substack{n\geq k \\ n\equiv k\!\!\pmod{2}}}\!\!\!\binom{n}{\frac{k+n}{2}}\tau^n+\sum_{\substack{n\geq k \\ n\equiv k\!\!\pmod{2}}}\!\!\!\binom{n}{\frac{n-k}{2}}\tau^n\right]. $$
By mapping $n$ into $k+2r$ we get
$$ \pi\tau^k\sum_{r\geq 0}\binom{2r+k}{r}\tau^{2r}$$
which is clearly related to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4\tau^2}}=\sum_{r\geq 0}\binom{2r}{r}\tau^{2r}$.

Comment: Do you think one could use contour integration here?

Comment: @Melz: definitely so, since we want to find $$\frac{1}{2}\text{Re}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{e^{ikx}}{1-\tau(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})}\,dx $$ which only depends on the residues of $\frac{x^{k}}{\tau x^2-x+\tau}$ at its poles.

Comment: Could you briefly explain why the upper bound is $2\pi$?

Comment: @Melz: the original integral is defined on $(0,\pi)$, but it is equivalent to an integral over $(0,2\pi)$ (or $(-\pi,\pi)$) by symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

You can express $$\cos (nx)=\sum_{r=0}^{\lfloor \frac n2\rfloor} (-1)^r { n\choose 2r} \cos^{n-2r}x\sin^{2r}x$$ 
 Now you can use substitution $t= \tan\frac x2$.

Comment: I believe it is more practical to leave $\cos(kx)$ as it is, but expand $\frac{1}{1-2\tau\cos(x)}$ as a Fourier series.